# Converge in Probability and Big Oh pee (1)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

I have read an econometrics textbook on "converge in distribution" and found the following sentence.

\begin{equation}
 \text{If} \hspace{0.25 cm} Z_{N} \xrightarrow{d} Z, Z_{N} = \large{O_p}(1)  
\end{equation}
That is, if a random variable $Z_n$ converges in distribution to $Z$, $Z_N$ is bounded in probability.
The textbook states that this is easy to verify. However, I cannot figure it out at the moment. thus, could you please help me prove the statement above?
Your helps are highly appreciated and Thank you very much.

Comment: Choose $M$ such that $P(Z>M)<\epsilon) $ and such that $M$ is a  continuity point for $F_Z$. Then use the fact that $P(Z_n>M)<\epsilon)  \to P(Z>M)<\epsilon) $. Do a similar thing for $P(Z<-M)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ravi.